# moment.js always returns 0 for minutes()

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I am trying to convert a moment into local time. However, when I try to get the minutes value from the moment it returns 0 even though it clearly is not 0 as can be seen from the picture the minutes is actually 35. Likewise, even if I do not try to get the minutes and format it to local time the minutes are again set to 0. In the example below 12:00 PM gets returned. What am I doing wrong and how do I correctly get the minutes portion of the moment or just as good how do I format it to local time with out the minutes being set to 0?

[image]

**EDIT**
As suggested in the comments formatting like `console.log(m.local().format('hh:mm'))` does not have any effect the min are still disregarded. See image.

Also, I'm using version `"moment": "^2.29.3"`

[image]

Comment: what if you `console.log(m.local().format('hh:mm'))`? I get `6:38` (correct local time for Italy) https://jsfiddle.net/xkjm3ap5/

Comment: Using the example provided above it returns 12:00

Comment: how about the linked fiddle? what does that output in your console?

Comment: Please share code, not pictures of code! Something other people can test and run.

Comment: I think you can manage to type 6 lines of code, not to mention the pasted code would not show the debug info.